# Programmatically add a variable header to a rollover log created using RollingRandomAccessFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j

I need to display a Java String value in the header of every rollover log created by RollingRandomAccessFileAppender. This string keeps changing on every size based rollover

Tried to use `PatternLayout:withHeader()` but this repeats the same header value in every rollover log file.

Is there an inbuilt functionality for this ? Or is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Subclass and implement your own functionality? After you've gone through the documentation to make sure the functionality doesn't exist.

Comment: But `PatternLayout` is a final class

Comment: Then you'll need to extend its superclass and copy the functionality.